# Designing for iPhone resolutions with Sketch 3

Tags: iphone, adaptive-ui

Im new to Sketch 3 and am designing an iPhone app to be responsive across all resolutions.

I have been following the size guides on here http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions which have been really helpful but I am trying the figure out the best workflow to cover resolutions for iPhone 5, 6 and 6+.

Will I essentially have to create 3 artboards at each pixel size of the device or is there a better way to handle this in Sketch?

I tried using the export functionality but this just gives you the retina graphics.

Would be good to get your thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

Sketch 3 also users to export at different resolutions. After adding different resolutions using the plus button and exporting( with png or which ever type you pick) you can drag and drop them directly into xcode's assests folder. If you need to export an entire artboard you can click the artboar(s) titles after selecting make exportable It even creates files using the nomenclature that Xcode uses to manage assests. 
Sketch does a great good at handling exporting and it's a workflow that works well. I find it a lil simpler than exporting with photoshop.